# How to add data programatically to the links in the left quick launch in SP2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, quick-launch, quick-edit

I want a feature where users can manage links that they can see in a quick way, and they can reorder it, and there's a way to display it on the master page via rest for example.

I fount the myquicklinks.aspx page but it doesn't seem to have a REST way to download from it, and it doesn't have a way to reorder the items.

Then I found the quicklanuch links shown below. This appears on the master page and has a reorder ability which is what I want. The only problem is, our users already have links from SP2010 through a custom solution, and we need to import that data to this.

Does anyone know where exactly this data is being stored, and how to add data to it?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: check if this help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms427791(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As the article that Waqas Sarwar links to mentions, the QuickLaunch links are stored in the `SPWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch` property.  Here are links to various documentation pages on MSDN that you might find useful:

[`SPWeb.Navigation` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.navigation.aspx)

[`SPNavigation` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigation_members.aspx)

[`SPNavigation.QuickLaunch` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigation.quicklaunch.aspx)

I'm not *absolutely* certain if it's accessible via the REST API, but my guess is that since `Navigation` is a property of `SPWeb` then, yes, it should be accessible.

To add data to the QuickLaunch, you would create new [`SPNavigationNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigationnode.aspx) objects which represent the links, and add them to the `SPWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch` [node collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigationnodecollection_members.aspx).